# How to dynamically change Default Schema name in Code-Based Migration .resx file?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, migration, codebase

I have **code-based migration** implementation in my project `(Windows Form Application - Entity Framework 6)`. I want to change(update) `Default Schema name` dynamically in Migration `.resx` file.

**What i tried from my side**
Already tried with this things but not working when i want to set schema name different
i.e. Migration generated with Oracle database schema name `PDBADMIN` and want to change `PDBTEST` schema name in migration file dynamically. I set dynamic schema name at all place in Migration file also. But when migration executed with new database then all table created successfully except `__MigrationHistory`.Because i found in Migration `.resx` file have some fix default schema name. So, i want to resolve this with some dynamically change(update) default schema name in `.resx` file.
**Example code (Not works)**

I manually replaced default schema name in `.resx` file but not allow to apply same migration to another database in Oracle (After migration execute database permission revoked - You can not use that database with your project only when you want to use Oracle) .

> base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
> modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Name");

Looking some good solutions to update migration file generated .resx default schema name dynamically through code and it will apply during migration execution.

Reference : [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!